# Add two sub-images into one new image using emgu cv

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have two images with different dimensions and I want to create another large image includes them vertically.

```
private Image<Gray, Byte> newImage(Image<Gray, Byte> image1, Image<Gray, Byte> image2)
    {
        int ImageWidth = 0;
        int ImageHeight = 0;

   //get max width
        if (image1.Width > image2.Width)
            ImageWidth = image1.Width;
        else
            ImageWidth = image2.Width;

  //calculate new height
        ImageHeight = image1.Height + image2.Height;

 //declare new image (large image).
        Image<Gray, Byte> imageResult = new Image<Gray, Byte>(ImageWidth, ImageHeight);


        imageResult.ROI = new Rectangle(0, 0, image1.Width, image1.Height);
        image1.CopyTo(imageResult);
        imageResult.ROI = new Rectangle(0, image1.Height, image2.Width, image2.Height);
        image2.CopyTo(imageResult);



        return imageResult;
    }
```

The returned image is a black image and doesn't contain the two images, please help me where's the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I solved the problem, the correct way is put my answer here or delete my question post or what?.

Comment: Post it as an answer

Answer (score 5):

Your approach was correct. You simply had to remove the ROI. Just add at the end:

```
imageResult.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;
```

The Final Result shoul look like this:

```
imageResult.ROI = new Rectangle(0, 0, image1.Width, image1.Height);
image1.CopyTo(imageResult);
imageResult.ROI = new Rectangle(0, image1.Height, image2.Width, image2.Height);
image2.CopyTo(imageResult);
imageResult.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution in the following:

```
private Image<Gray, Byte> newImage(Image<Gray, Byte> image1, Image<Gray, Byte> image2)
{
    int ImageWidth = 0;
    int ImageHeight = 0;

//get max width
    if (image1.Width > image2.Width)
        ImageWidth = image1.Width;
    else
        ImageWidth = image2.Width;

//calculate new height
    ImageHeight = image1.Height + image2.Height;

//declare new image (large image).
    Image<Gray, Byte> imageResult;

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Math.Max(image1.Width , image2.Width), image1.Height + image2.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.DrawImage(image1.Bitmap, 0, 0);
            g.DrawImage(image2.Bitmap, 0, image1.Height);

        }

        imageResult = new Image<Gray, byte>(bitmap);



    return imageResult;
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for large bitmaps (10600w x 9980h)